# Safari comment overflow issue with minimum font size setting

Tags: bug, comments, design, safari

In Safari 6.0.2, comments are overflowing on the page after selecting "add / show more comments".

This only happens when setting "Never use font sizes smaller than" to *14 or higher* under **Safari > Preferences > Advanced > Accessibility**.

I used this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk) as a test page.

**Before**

[image]

---

**Change Setting**

[image]

---

**Select More Comments**

[image]

---

**Comment Overflow**

[image]

---

I tested this issue on an [Ask Different post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5435/what-are-some-tips-or-tricks-for-terminal-in-mac-os-x) and there were no overflow problems.